# cant access website through domain name but accessing through IP address for a laravel project in ubuntu droplet

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, digital-ocean

I made some apache2 configuration changes for an Ubuntu droplet in DigitalOcean and restarted apache2 and saved the changes. It worked. However when I logged out from server connection and rebooted my pc, The domain name did not show the website contents, although the droplet IP address is working fine. Can anyone give me a permanent solution on how to fix this?

Note: This is for a PHP Laravel project using Ubuntu Droplet in DigitalOcean web hosting. Other Configurations and Environment setups are done and working.

Comment: What happens when you go to it by domain name?

Comment: Make sure your DNS Settings are correct. Check your A records, specifically.

Comment: when I log out of server/command line and shut down pc/laptop, and when I reopen my device to go to the domain name, the website dissapears, just showing a contruction Image, But the IP is working fine. Dammeul